# python datetime %d causes problems

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to work with dates and datetime

```
from datetime import date,datetime

d1 = datetime.strptime('2008-03-03','%y-%m-%d')  //the %d is colored different!
d2 = datetime(2008, 2 ,3)

print(date.today())
print(d1 - d2)
```

error:

```
time data '2008-03-03' does not match format '%y-%m-%d'
```

What I'm doing wrong?
The name of the file is test.py.
Thats the woule file, and I run it with rightclick in VScode 'run python file in terminal'

Comment: use capital Y: `d1 = datetime.strptime('2008-03-03','%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: stays the same %d still 'escapes'

Comment: Use [http://strftime.net/](http://strftime.net/) to check what each code does if you're wondering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must write %Y not %y, Then the code becomes

```
d1 = datetime.strptime('2008-03-03','%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the %y...

> %y    Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.   00, 01, ...

> 99 %-y    Year without century as a decimal number.   0, 1, ..., 99

> %Y    Year with century as a decimal number.  2013, 2019 etc.

I've fiddled your code on https://www.mycompiler.io/view/B6EhAzCnd83, with the fix:

```
from datetime import date,datetime

d1 = datetime.strptime('2008-03-03','%Y-%m-%d')
d2 = datetime(2008, 2 ,3)

print(date.today())
print(d1 - d2)
```

outputs:

> 2022-04-01 29 days, 0:00:00
>
> [Execution complete with exit code 0]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's an cosmetic problem:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133127

Code works now, no error, but highlighting is still off, even if I use Extension Bisect and deactivate all extensions, or manually deactivate all extensions.

VSCode 1.66

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this error in VSCodium as well. I also used Extension Bisect and it did not change anything. The %d is highlighted with extensions on or off, and while using %Y or %y. I can reproduce the error using strftime also. You don't deserve to be downvoted imo, as this looks like a bug. You might want to reopen that github issue or resubmit as a bug report